# Reset a crashed device (Intel Wireless-N 7260) without reboot

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers

I have a [problem with an Intel Wireless-N 7260 card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517463/intel-corporation-wireless-n-7260-card-dies-randomly) in my laptop. When it dies, I have to reboot to use it again.

Is there a way to reload the used modules somehow?

I tried removing them with `sudo rmmod <modulename>` an reload it, I also reloaded all modules that depend to each other for that device, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to reset the hardware without rebooting?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 32bit.

Comment: You have already tried reloading the used module and it's not enough. It seems that the hardware peripheral needs to be reset. The solution is necessarily specific to that hardware or to a class of hardware (maybe hardware on the same bus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is too old, but I have a solution that might work for others.

Firstly, get the PCIID using:

```bsh
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Then do:

```
echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/remove > /dev/null
```

replacing the PCIID appropriately
Wait a couple of seconds and do:

```
echo '3' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan > /dev/null
```

Or, to create a script, simply have the following:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 | awk -F' ' '{print $1;}' | head -n1 | read PCI
echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:$PCI/remove > /dev/null
sleep 2
echo '3' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan > /dev/null
```

Comment: I don't have that broken hardware any more, but this seems promising, so I will mark this as "solved untested"